# bash: grepping contents of column which is dynamic

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, grep

I have data as following :

[image]

What i need to get is the `OS_NATIVE_NAME` of a particular `DEVICE`.

I know one way is to print its column value using:

```
awk '{print $*col_num*}'
```

But the column number for this `OS_NATIVE_NAME` is not fixed. This is because, other fields like `STATUS` can have values different (could be multiple sometime), which is causing a problem of not having fixed column number for the `OS_NATIVE_NAME`, which is the required data for my tests.

How can i grep that particular column's content??

Comment: Can you assume that the columns begin in fixed character positions, or does that have to be determined dynamically from the header line?

Comment: Columns format & order is fixed. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Is the output tab delimited or space delimited?

Comment: space limited.

I tried like this also.

# vxdisk -e list | awk '{print $1"\t\t\t" $6}'

DEVICE              OS_NATIVE_NAME

disk_0                  invalid

disk_1                  invalid

intel_ssd0_0                sdc

So you can see here, i am getting different data from different columns.

Comment: BTW: Can you please add the example data as `code blocks`? With an image it's hard to do test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if($i=="OS_NATIVE_NAME"){s=index($0,$i); l=index($0,$(i+1))-s}}}
 $1=="disk_0"{print substr($0,s,l)}' file
```

- `NR==1` if it's the first line (the header line), `NR` is awks internal variable for the current line number being processed.

  - `for(i=1;i<NF;i++)` loop trough the fields. `NF` is awks internal variable for the number of fields in the current line.
  - `$i=="OS_NATIVE_NAME"` since, we're looping trough each field, check if the field value equals `OS_NATIVE_NAME`
  - `s=index(...)` find the position of the start of the field and save it for later. [`index()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) is awks string function to get the position of the occurence of a string (here the value of $i, hence `OS_NATIVE_NAME`) in another string (here `$0`, hence the whole line).
  - `l=index(...)-s` get the length of the field and save it for later: same priciple as before, but to get the length we must substract `s` from it.
- `$1=="disk_0"` find the `DEVICE` you are searching in the first field (`disk_0` in the example). `$1` represents the first field.

  - `{print substr($0,s,l)}` finally print for each line, the string started at position `s`, with length `l`. [`substr()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) is awks string function to cut a string (here `$0`; the whole line) from position `s` with length `l` (the two varibale we prevously extracted while processing line 1)

---

Prints (regardless of where the field is in the input):

```
sda
```

Comment: I thought this
but this will not work all the time, because position of OS_NATIVE_NAME string is not same as that of its data.
right??

Comment: @AmitM I think I don't understand, can you give an example? Why should the position of `OS_NATIVE_NAME` not be the same as its data?

Comment: Its working (y) 
but i couldn't understand it completely.

Comment: Can you elaborate it little bit more...
-thanks

Comment: @AmitM I edit the answer to be mor specific. Hope it's clear now =)

Comment: Its better now. :)

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution:

```
data=$(vxdisk -e list)
devices=$(sed 's/ .*//' <<< "$data")
# I'm just guessing that the relevant column starts in column 80
os_native_name=$(cut -c80- <<< "$data")
row=0
for dev in $devices; do let row++; if [[ "$dev" = disk_1 ]]; then break; fi; done
# now we know our desired data is on the row'th line of os_native_name
# you can retrieve it for instance with
sed -n "$row p" <<< "$os_native_name"
```

Comment: This isnt working..

Comment: It worked in my tests, can you give more information?

Comment: Can you tell me how can i upload image here?
Data is not getting pasted properly..

Comment: You can't upload an image to comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try below command:

```
vmdisk -e list | awk 'NR==1 { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { ix[$i] = i } } NR>1 { print $ix["OS_NATIVE_NAME"] }'
```